# Is there a way to listen control keys (ASCII < 10) event with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard, ascii

My question is not about "Ctrl" keys but the non printable keys not present on any keyboard but useful for prefix a barcode when it's read by a scanner in HID mode.
At the moment, I can listen on keydown event a lot of chars but when my barcode scanner is configured to prefix the barcode by an ASCII char like SOH (ASCII code 1) or STX (2), ETX (3), EOT (4) …
I have no trace of any event …
Maybe, Chrome, Firefox … do not care of these …
My code to test is quite simple, I just log keydown events fired on document …

**EDIT**
I precise that the question is about javascript runing on navigator (Edge, Chrome, Safari, Firefox ...) and not in node. I have to listen the barcode scanner on a web page.

Comment: Not sure if they are directly present in the event object properties, but you could try to read the value of the entered string (use input event for real time scanning) using [`charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) ..?

Comment: Your problem lies somewhere else than low level codes. Event doesn't depend on keycode, you can dispach/catch an empty KeyboardEvent. If you don't see any events - there is none.

Comment: @Teemu: The imput event is only in inputs ... The purpose to use a barcode scanner is to listen read barcodes outside any inputs. Barcode scanners work like a physical keyboard but can send specific keys as prefix or suffix. The goal is to be aware that the received chars are sent by the barcode scanner and not by a keyboard. Professionnal barcode scanners could be configurate with specific control keys. I hope it's clear, my english is far from perfection ^^

Comment: @SvenLiivak: How could you know when the event is emit without event ??? I made some tests, and listen all keydown events on DOM document. When my barcode scanner is configured to prefix all barcodes with ASCII code 1, I only received events after the prefix. I think navigators do not emit events with these ASCII codes, but I was unabled to find the information on Google ...

Comment: Yeah, I realized that input won't fire on document afterwards. But are programs for those "_professional scanners_" written with JS? You could give an input a try, just focus on an input before scanning, and check if the non-printables can be read from the value. Maybe you could develope the idea further ... Just a side note, all web-based scanners (excluding mobile apps etc.) I've used, have entered the scanned code to an input element.

Comment: @Teemu: These scanners does not have JS programs... I have code a small library which use RxJS to emit events on barcode scaning in a web page (https://github.com/tii-bruno/physical-barcode-reader-observer). I use it on an Ionic project and a collegue of mine use it as a standalone in a JS / PHP project. The purpose is to listen everywhere to avoid forcing user to be in input because it's useless. If you know you received a barcode you can do some actions depend on it. If you can't be sure event come from the barcode scanner it could be simulate by the keyboard and I want to avoid that.

Comment: Ah ... Maybe my comment was a bit ambiguous, I meant the programs receiving the scans, the UI.

Comment: @BrunoDesprez Your problem is bit confusing, lets clarify it. First the confusing part: _I have no trace of any event_ What you mean by that? If you have no event whatsoever then keycode (one property of nonexisting event) is completely unimportant. But then you have said: _I can listen on keydown event a lot of chars_ ... so there is an event afterall..? and you can receive something from it? or? If you do, could you please be so kind and post a codesnippet which produces this result?

Comment: @SvenLiivak: I have no problem to listen keydown events. The problem is on a limited ASCII chars, there is no event. The barcode reader that i use is an little device connected in USB or Bluetooth and emulate a keyboard (HID mode). When the device read a barcode, it sends read chars like if someone pressed in an a keyboard. But With some configuration, you can tell to the device to begin each read barcode with a prefix. And it's possible to define some ASCII codes aren't present on a normal keyboard (SOH, STX ...). And these chars are send to the OS but I don't received event on web browsers

Comment: Does focused input receive the barcode with pre/postfix?

Comment: @SvenLiivak: Yes if the prefix/postfix are an excisting keyboard key (letters, numbers, Ctrl, Shift …) But none of special ACSII codes like SOH, STX …). I begin to think I'm not clear, because I really have the impression to repeat myself …

Comment: I have heard about scanners which instead of KeyboardEvent fire InputEvent. But in this case a scanned result should be inserted into focused field. As you confirmed (many times, sorry :)) that focused input doesnt receive anything then it must be scanner side "feature". You can test whether it's true by reading HID events with xev (like Walker suggested) or alternative for Windows but... if no events are fired by browser then it's out of your hands. I would concentrate on creating "normal"prefix and/or timer based solution.

Comment: @SvenLiivak: Finally, we have the same diagnostic. It's why my question is centered on ASCII characters which code is under 10. I'm pretty sure that it's because of browsers but I would like to be sure ^^. Your proposition about to concentrate «on creating "normal"prefix and/or timer based solution» is what I've already done with my little lib (github.com/tii-bruno/physical-barcode-reader-observer). ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can test if barcode scanner is working by running the `xev` command on a linux machine (idk about another OS's), if xev outputs something, the browser should trigger the keyboard event. If xev does not output, the scanner is not working as expected.